# Ajax update works for radios, checkboxes but not a button

Tags: javascript, ajax

On click, I want the form to process and update based on which button is clicked.

html:

```
<input type="button" value="5.00" name="updatefield" id="updatefield" class="chooseit">
```

have also tried:

```
<button name="updatefield" id="updatefield" class="chooseit">5.00</button>

<button name="updatefield" id="updatefield" class="chooseit" type="button">5.00</button>

<button name="updatefield" id="updatefield" class="chooseit" type="button" value="5.00">5.00</button>

<button name="updatefield" id="updatefield" class="chooseit" type="submit" value="5.00">5.00</button>
```

When I change **button** to anything besides "button," (radio,checkbox, etc) the form process as expected. (The 5.00 is passed to the overall page total as +5.00)

View.js:

```
    events: {
         'click button.chooseit': 'chooseIt',
    },
```

processing.js

```
    chooseDonate: function(updatefield) {
    this.set('updatefield', updatefield);
    var that = this;
    $.post('index.php?route=info/updateinfo', this.toJSON(), function(data) {
        qc.event.trigger('updateAll', data);
        that.updateForm(data);
    }, 'json').error();
},
```

Are buttons handled differently?  Can't figure out why radios/checkboxes work, but not buttons.

Comment: What works when it's not a button and what doesn't work when it is? Yes, "button", "submit" and "img" are different than "text", "checkbox" etc... A button have a value when you click on it, but it otherwise not included in a form submission.

Comment: Still vague, this question is.

Comment: Onclick, the form updates the total value. The button value (for example, 5.00) should update the form to +5.00 -- this only works if i set the input type to radio or checkbox. Will update my question.

Comment: What framework are you using? Because your View.js is suggesting that maybe you're using backbone or something to that effect?

Comment: Opencart, but this code is not native. Was written by someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the framework you are using. If I understand `events:{'click button.chooseit': 'chooseIt',}` you bind the click to a function called `chooseIt`. It would be nice to see that function too.

But to answer your question "Are buttons handled differently?", well, it depends on what type of button. There are `<input type="button">`, `<input type="submit">`, `<input type="image">`, `<input type="reset">`, `<button type="button">`,  `<button type="submit">`, `<button type="menu">` and  `<button type="reset">`. If `type="submit"` or `type="image"` the form is submitted. If `type="reset"` the controls in the form are reset to their initial value. If `type="menu"` a popup menu defined via its designated `<menu>`-element is displayed. If `type="button"` nothing special happens unless you have added a click-handler.

For the thing you are trying to do, there is no difference in plain javascript. I have added an example below where I use `<input type="radio">`, `<input type="checkbox">`, `<input type="button">`, `<button type="button">` and `<select>`, and they are all using the same function to set the value of `<output>` to the latest clicked value. (`type="checkbox"` get special treatment since it can be clicked to uncheck)

So to find what's wrong, you need to dig into your framework and see what it is doing. A common mistake is that the form get submitted, and it can happen so fast that it looks like nothing happened. You can detect that, for example if you enable "sticky log" in your browsers developer console, so that the log is kept even if the page is reloaded.

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
function setOutput(event) {
  var value = this.value;
  if (this.type === 'checkbox') {
    if (!this.checked) value = '';
  }
  output.value = value;
}
document.querySelectorAll('input, button').forEach(
  function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', setOutput);
  }
);
document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(
  function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('change', setOutput);
  }
);
```

```css
fieldset{
  display:inline-block;
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
fieldset p {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-size:80%;
}
```

```html
<p>Proof of concept that the type of input element doesn't matter in this case.</p>
<form id="form1">
  <fieldset>
    <p>&lt;input type="radio"&gt;</p>
    <label><input value="5" type="radio" name="radioValue">5</label>
    <label><input value="10" type="radio" name="radioValue">10</label>
    <label><input value="20" type="radio" name="radioValue">20</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <p>&lt;input type="checkbox"&gt;</p>
    <label><input value="5" type="checkbox" name="chkValue">5</label>
    <label><input value="10" type="checkbox" name="chkValue">10</label>
    <label><input value="20" type="checkbox" name="chkValue">20</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <p>&lt;input type="button"&gt;</p>
    <input value="5" type="button" name="ibtnValue">
    <input value="10" type="button" name="ibtnValue">
    <input value="20" type="button" name="ibtnValue">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <p>&lt;button type="button"&gt;</p>
    <button value="5" type="button" name="btnValue">5</button>
    <button value="10" type="button" name="btnValue">10</button>
    <button value="20" type="button" name="btnValue">20</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <p>&lt;select&gt;</p>
    <select>
      <option value="">--Select value---</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <p>Last selected value: <output id="output"></output></p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help! There was an event on an *additional* js script that I had overlooked that was missing the class ID (missing because I'm adding functionality, so this js file wasn't aware of the new button, yet).  I'm going to accept this as the answer because @some was spot on by suggesting to dig around the framework, because that's specifically what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

If your `button` is inside a form, it's probably submitting it (that is their default behavior).

Try adding a type attribute to tell your browser you don't want that to happen:

```
<button name="updatefield" id="updatefield" class="chooseit" type="button">5.00</button>
```

Comment: No luck. I do want the form to process this, but only onclick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the button a value such as below:

```
<button name="updatefield" id="updatefield" class="chooseit" type="button" value="5.00">5.00</button>
```

Comment: Same result; when I click, nothing happens - nothing in console log either. It's as if I never clicked.

Do buttons require special parameters in order to work like this? I'm positively puzzled how the same code works for radios & checkboxes, but not buttons.

Comment: hum try type="submit"

Comment: No luck with type="submit" either.

Comment: Just have to ask. The button is indeed also inside the form tag right?

Comment: Correct. the only code I changed was the input type and js declaring it is no longer a radio input.

Comment: can you post your entire form code from begin form tag to end form tag?